# May I attach a file to a Group?

Tags: redmine

El-Goog says nobody has attached a file to a group before; I only find noise when I searched for "redmine attachment group".

However, this test passes; I can apparently attach a file to a Group's parent class, "Principal":

```
def test_attach_a_file_to_a_group
  set_tmp_attachments_directory
  group = Group.find_by_lastname!('B Team')

  a = Attachment.new(:container => group,
                     :file => uploaded_test_file("japanese-utf-8.txt", "text/plain"),
                     :author => User.find(1))
  assert a.save!
  assert_equal 'japanese-utf-8.txt', a.filename
  assert_equal 'Principal', a.container_type
end
```

So where do I go from here? Should my plugin re-implement the "groups/_form.html.erb" file and add the partial that displays the "Choose files" button? Or should I patch something into Group first, to make it ready to use the file that it probably doesn't know is attached to it?

I will report back here what I discover...

Answer (score 0):

It seems I can't do it. I will document here how far I got.

First I added this line to the test:

```
assert_equal 1, group.attachments.count
```

That forced me to patch Group and add `acts_as_attachable`. The heart of the patch is:

```
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      acts_as_attachable
    end
  end
```

The next step was to copy `app/views/groups/_form.html.erb` into my plugin's `app` folder, and add the lines that display and add new attachments:

```
<% extend AttachmentsHelper %>
<%= link_to_attachments @group, :thumbnails => true %>
<p><%=l(:label_attachment_plural)%><br /><%= render partial: 'attachments/form', locals: { container: @group } %></p>
```

That required me to patch GroupsController, alias `update` to `update_with_attachments`, and add the line that saves the attachment:

```
      @group.save_attachments params[:attachments]
```

Finally, because `acts_as_attachable` assumes you have a project, I had to add `def project; nil; end` to my Group.

And that's all I could do. When I manually tested, I got a record that responded to a lookup URI with a 404. `https://our.domain.com/attachments/thumbnail/6053?size=96`. I put a `Rails.logger.warn` line above every `render_404` and similar that I could find, and I never figured out which one was rendering the 404. The AttachmentsController found the Attachment correctly, but that was as far as I could trace what was going on.

So now I'm going to retire all this new code, and go with a system where my code that needs a Group to have an image just finds one by looking up Attachments in Projects related to that Group.